# I have a vector that is filled up within a loop. When I step through the code, the final vector looks different to when I let the code run

Tags: c++, vector

To elaborate, I have a global vector defined above `main` as: `vector<PCWSTR> objectIdentifiers` (I have no experience with PCWSTR, but this is the format used by the windows portable devices API).

I have a line within a function `recursiveEnumerate()` that fills in the vector like so:

```
objectIdentifiers.push_back(objectID);
```

Where `objectID` is a PCWSTR.

I have placed a breakpoint in Visual studio on this line, and the vector fills up every loop correctly. I stepped through code until the size of `objectIdentifiers` was 10, and this is what it looks like in the debugger:
[image: stepping through code gives this result]
Which seems fine, since there are very few gaps.

When I run the code without placing a breakpoint on the line, and instead placing a breakpoint at the very end of `main`, when I watch the vector, I get this:
[image: running code with no breakpoint gives this]

The first object is correct (L"DEVICE"), but I'm not entirely sure what has happened afterward. The result appears to be different every time, except for the first entry (which is always L"DEVICE").

I'm guessing the reason is that I'm adding entries to the vector incorrectly. Is using `push_back` to add PCWSTR's to a vector causing these problems?

Comment: If you want to store string, store strings, not pointers.  Have a `vector<std::wstring>` or a vector of similar string type.  Storing addresses in the vector is a quick way to get things all fouled up.

Comment: From where are you getting ObjectIds? Are they null terminated? from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) it says PCWSTR should be null terminated.

Comment: Please paste your code here

Comment: Where is the guarantee that this pointer will be unique for all strings, and will never become invalid at some point?  You should replace your `std::vector<PCWSTR>` with `std::vector<std::wstring>`, and I bet your problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys!

I'm getting the PCWSTR from the WIndows Portable Devices API. Basically every object (file) on a device has a unique identifier (the entries in the vector o1, o2, o3 etc) which I obtain from `EnumObjects`, one of the API's functions.

I'm trying to get a list of all the object identifiers on a device

Comment: @A_toaster The *identifiers* are unique *strings*.  That is not the same thing as the pointers being unique.  Use the `std::vector<std::wstring>` -- It will work the same way, with the *big* difference being that you will be storing strings, not pointers.  The `std::wstring` will take the data that is pointed to by the PCWSTR and make it a string object, thus it won't be corrupted or just go up in a puff of smoke if the original pointer changes what it points to, gets invalidated, etc.  Also, the line `objectIdentifiers.push_back(objectID);` will not need to be changed -- it will just work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks Paul, your idea worked perfectly, although I'm a bit embarassed that I didn't even try this solution in the first place.

Thanks again